# adding svg Image front of select options

Tags: html, css, vue.js, drop-down-menu, sass

Currently, I have the following code which gives me the required drop-down but I wanted to know how can I change the tick mark to image in the options

```
   <select class="appsearchfilter__seldiv--select">
      <option class="appsearchfilter__seldiv--option">
        <FlatOption class="appsearchfilter__seldiv--option" /> /*-->this is the SVG import and it is component of vuejs */
        Flat
      </option>
      <option class="appsearchfilter__seldiv--option">Door</option>
      <option class="appsearchfilter__seldiv--option">APT</option>
    </select>
```

By this I get following View 
[image]

**I want to replace the tick mark with the Image that I have added in the**

Below is my CSS file:

```
  &__seldiv {
    &--select {
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 22px;
      margin-left: 321px;
      width: 217px;
      height: 44px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      border: solid 1px #bababa99;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-stretch: normal;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 1.2;
      letter-spacing: normal;
      text-align: left;
      color: #0e1122;
    }
    &--option {

      color: #ffffff;
    }
```

I have following import for SVG

**import FlatOption from "@/assets/FlatOption.svg";**

I have tried to make this change but still, it dint work

```
<option
            class="appsearchfilter__seldiv--select--option"
            :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + require('@/assets/FlatOption.svg') + ')' }"
          >Flat</option>
```